# Inner join with like operator?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working with access and trying to create a sql-query.

Basically I got two tables, that I want to join. The first one has a "short form" of the name and a value. The second one has a "complex form" of the name and another value.

The tables look like this:

## Test_Tabelle1

### Feld1;Feld2

```
asdf;14
test;21
```

## Test_Tabelle2

### Feld1;Feld2

```
asdf_1;16
asdf_2;16
test_1;24
test_2;22
```

## How the result should look

### Test_Tabelle2.Feld1;Test_Tabelle1.Feld2

```
asdf_1;14
asdf_2;14
test_1;21
test_2;21
```

Basically: If "asdf" (from Test_Tabelle1.Feld1) is a part of Test_Tabelle2.Feld1 it should join both. Same with "test". How can I get a result?

I tried the following code, which seems correct, but doesn't get me any result.

```
SELECT Test_Tabelle2.Feld1, Test_Tabelle1.Feld2
FROM Test_Tabelle1
INNER JOIN Test_Tabelle2 ON Test_Tabelle2.Feld1 LIKE ("%" & Test_Tabelle1.Feld1 & "%");
```

Comment: For future questions (of if this q isn't solved), please use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to supply sample data and expected result. It's much easier to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MS-Access uses `*` where you have `%`

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/like-operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931

*(One of many reasons I hate MS-Access, it's too proprietary)*